# should I validate uniques in Mongoose before using save?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am new to Node and Javascript in general and I was wondering if I should validate uniqueness by using FindOne before using .save.

My User schema does have Unique:true set for email and username and my current code works like a charm since mongoose returns an error message for uniques.

I wanted to know if it was better to validate for uniqueness before attempting to save for effiency or something?

Current code as follow :

```
export const createUser = (data) => {
  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
     const userData = JSON.parse(data);
     const newUser = new User(userData);
     await newUser.save((err) => {
       if(err){
         const msg = err.errmsg.toLowerCase();
         const errormsg = msg.includes('email') ? 'Email already in use' : msg.includes('username') ? 'Username already in use' : 'Unexpected error.'
         reject(JSON.stringify({error: errormsg}));
       }
       resolve(JSON.stringify({status: 200, created: true}));
     });
  });
};
```

Implemented here :

```
public register(req, res){
   validateRegisterForm(req.body).then(data => {
    createUser(data).then(resp => {
      res.send(resp);
    }).catch(err => {
      res.send(err);
    })
  }).catch(err => {
      res.send(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: One usually define columns as unique to maintain data integrity, because that's the work of databases. Rely the application layer to keep this important concept is not a good idea.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this is a Restful API triggered when post/register is sent and only allows from domains and subdomains origin